# Programmatically Removing a Button from a Window in Cocoa OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsbutton

I need to programmatically remove a button from a window in Cocoa but the only method close to this was dealloc in NSObject, but this is not what I want to do.  Is there a way to actually delete the button from the window not just deallocate its memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NSButton is a subclass of NSControl, which itself is a subclass of NSView.

You should be able to remove the button from it's superview by calling `-removeFromSuperView` on the button instance.

Answer (score 10):

Send the [removeFromSuperview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/removeFromSuperview) message to the button instance.

Though perhaps you just want to hide it instead (using `setHidden:`)?

Comment: Worth pointing out that views retain their subviews, which means that removing the button from its superview will cause the superview to release it, possibly resulting in it deallocking. I agree that hiding the button is probably more useful.

Comment: +1 for "maybe just hide it" suggestion and a further suggestion that perhaps *disabling* it. Removing UI that's not currently available is not recommended. The user should know it's there so they know they have to do something to enable it.